# How to check the existence of two columns' data in two different tables ? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two different tables in two different databases ..

what I want to do is to check if the data of two columns exist in the other table .. if it does exist count it and at the final I want the number of records that have matching in the other table.

example :

table_1

column_1 value = "dog"

column_2 value = "apple"

table_2

column_1 value = "dog"

column_2 value = "orange"

so here the first column values exist in both table but the second column is different so I don't want to count it .. I want to count where both values exist in the same record .

ps: Both column_1 and column_2 aren't primary key

is there a solution for it using MySQL ? because I used java to solve this but take a long time for 5 million records .

Comment: Where's the other database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an `INNER JOIN` on both tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.column_1 = t2.column_1
    AND t1.column_2 = t2.column_2
```

Comment: It works for small number of records , I tried it for 1 million record and the duration time about 24 sec , but the fetching time never ends , I left it running for 9 hours and still didn't finish .. any ideas ?

Comment: @Zizoo set p proper index for both tables.

Comment: I didn't understand you , but both tables have primary key column

Comment: @Zizoo I'm not talking about PK. Try this: `ALTER TABLE \`table_1\` ADD INDEX (\`column_1\`, \`column_2\`);
ALTER TABLE \`table_2\` ADD INDEX (\`column_1\`, \`column_2\`);`

Comment: Thank you .. I got the result in seconds :)

Comment: @Zizoo, no problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, one option is to use `exists`:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2 
    where t1.column1 = t2.column1 and
          t1.column2 = t2.column2
)
```

This will return a list of rows from the first table that have a corresponding matching row in the second.

Comment: can you explain what does the one after select mean ? ( select 1 from ... )

Comment: @Zizoo -- When using `exists`, the column you use in the `select` statement is arbitrary -- it really just returns true or false for those records that match the `where` criteria.  Depending on your needs, can be faster than using a `join`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation